# How to set the start position for ffmpeg filters?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a standard method of applying a ffmpeg filter from a named start position, or does this vary for different filters?

If I apply a blur for example, I can blur the whole clip easily, but if I wanted to blur from 5 secs in, how would I achieve that (without trimming out and concatinating back in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to use a filter that has [timeline support](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) (the `enable` option).

See list of filters with `ffmpeg -filters` and look for the `T` next to the name. Example:

```
Filters:
  T.. = Timeline support
  .S. = Slice threading
  ..C = Command support
  A = Audio input/output
  V = Video input/output
  N = Dynamic number and/or type of input/output
  | = Source or sink filter
[...]
 TSC avgblur           V->V       Apply Average Blur filter.
 T.. boxblur           V->V       Blur the input.
 T.C dblur             V->V       Apply Directional Blur filter.
 TSC gblur             V->V       Apply Gaussian Blur filter.
 T.. sab               V->V       Apply shape adaptive blur.
 T.. smartblur         V->V       Blur the input video without impacting the outlines.
 TS. unsharp           V->V       Sharpen or blur the input video.
 TSC yaepblur          V->V       Yet another edge preserving blur filter.
```

So all of these blur filters support it.

Example command to blur from timestamp 5 to end:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "boxblur=enable='gt(t,5)'" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

See [list of additional functions](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation).

If a filter does not have timeline support a workaround is to use *trim* and *setpts* filters to select the time of video to be filtered, then *overlay* or *concat* filters to place it. Should be several examples on this site.